# javascript variable inside a variable that is a block of html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a variable inside another variable which is a block of html code. It seems that you cannot just type in the name of the variable into the html code.

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper"></div>

    <script>
    var link = "https://google.com"
    var codeBlock = '<a href="link">' +
    'LINK TO GOOGLE' +
    '</a>';

    document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = codeBlock
    </script> 

</body>
```

I want the result to be a link to https://google.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for that:

```js
const link = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
const linktext = 'stackoverflow';

const link1 = 'https://google.com';
const linktext1 = 'google.com';

// template literals
let codeblock = `<a href="${link}">${linktext}</a>`;

// or string concatenation
codeblock += '<a href="' + link1 + '">' + linktext1 + '</a>';

document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = codeblock;
```

```css
a {  margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that helped (indirectly) I ended up doing something like: 


var codeBlock=<a href="${link}">link to google</a>

Comment: Ah ok, now i understand. I have edit my answer. You can see a running example with both syntaxes. The first one (template literals ES6) is more readable in my opinion. If you don't need IE11 support, i would use this syntax.